# Deserialize Json String to Object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to get weather data from online as json and then deserialize the json into an object that I can use. Here's my code:

```
public static RootObject7 GetWeather7(int zip)
    {
        var url = "http://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/forecast/us." + zip.ToString() + "?app_id=xxxxxxx&app_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var weather = new wunlocked();
        string json = weather.getJson(url);
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = (RootObject7)serializer.Deserialize<RootObject7>(json);
        return data;
    }
private string getJson(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm debugging, and what's happening is my RootObject7 data object is being created, and inside it has a "Forecast" object, which is supposed to contain a list of other information but instead it's null. I've already defined all of the classes (they're long, so if it's important, I'll post them but otherwise I don't think I need to). I've never done anything like this before so most of this came from other code examples on here that I've found, but obviously I didn't put them together correctly, since my object is always null but when I go to the url, there's valid xml there. I'm not sure if I need to be somehow converting the xml to json in my code, or if that is being done somehow? Like I said, I really don't know what I'm doing but if anyone has suggestions, that'd be great.

Comment: Instead of JavaScriptSerializer use Json.NET. And show Json and clasess.

Comment: When you build a dummy forecast using your own classes, and then *serialize* that, do you get JSON similar to what you get from the webservice?

Comment: in your debugger, put a breakpoint right after `string json = weather.getJson(url);` and see if the `json` variable is populated as expected.

Comment: Include the json string that returns from the web call.
Include the classes you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: I'd also get rid of all the body of getJson() and replace it with a call to httpClient.GetStringAsync()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize(json);
```

and then inspect the data object in the debugger - you may not need to deserialise to a fixed interface to get out the data you need. Using dynamic may also be a more robust solution to deal with upgrades to the service that may make a set interface/object more brittle.